# How do I execute background-position on a JavaScript page load

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to position the background with `background-position: center center;` but when you start scrolling and the javascript is activated, it gets the wrong positioning. Anyone have any suggestion?

**Check out the demo here:**
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G23Z0H5YSQCO

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Keep the image centered and move only in y-direction depending on scroll? In your case the center position would be overridden by the first calculated px value which depends on x-offset (which is usually 0)

Comment: I want the background to continue to be centered when you start scrolling down and keeping the animation at the same time. So Yes i want to keep the background centered and only move in y-direction depending on scroll. :)

Comment: Please fix the title ("backround-position")!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line to keep the horizontal centring and only change the y-position while scrolling:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundPosition = "center " + (-window.pageYOffset / speed) + "px";
```

So your example should then look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#myDiv {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/1200x400/000/fff');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  padding:20% 0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

body {height:1400px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
window.onscroll = function() {
var speed = 8;
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundPosition = "center " + (-window.pageYOffset / speed) + "px";
}
});
</script>

<div id="myDiv">
<h1>Headline</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<button>Call to action</button>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: … or set only `backgroundPositionY` to begin with, and leave X alone ;-)